# Cocoapods: "No Xcode project found, please specify one!"

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Cocoapods is giving me this error message when calling `pod init`:

```
[!] No Xcode project found, please specify one
```

I've...

1. called `sudo gem install cocoapods` and waited for it to install
2. dragged in my project directory folder "Hello" (see images)
3. called `pod init`

Here's my desktop:

[image]

What my directory folder "Hello looks like (sudo gem install cocoapods has already finished

[image]

What happens when I try to initialize the pod.

Why does that happen?

Comment: Try `cd /users/jonas/Desktop/Projekt\ Hello/Hello` before executing `pod init`

Comment: Did you find the solution

Comment: In my case, by mistake I used caps "CD"
e.g. $ CD /Users/hardikdarji/Desktop/test/demo/.....
fixed by $ cd /Users/hardikdarji/Desktop/test/demo/

Answer (score 41):

if you are using **REACT NATIVE** or **FLUTTER** ,make sure go to ios folder ,then pod init

```
cd ios
pod init
```

Comment: Getting "No Xcode project found, please specify one"
When running pod init in iOS folder.

Answer (score 13):

Just close the XCode and terminal once then restart the Terminal. Make sure you select the path to your project folder only.

After calling `cd /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Desktop/PROJECT_NAME` just call a command `~ls` and check if the list of the file contains your PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj. If this file is available, it means you can now set up `pod init`. Otherwise, you should navigate to the next level and find your PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you are in the correct directory where you .xcodeproj is located.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

Using terminal would still not work, so I just used the official Cocoapods application and it worked fine. Just download it, select new podfile and then your project and you're ready to go!

Comment: It works everytime. 
1) Cd path of your project directory. To get correct directory path drag your folder in terminal after typing "cd". Press enter.
2) type pod init and enter.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the problem was because of the space in the directory name.  I could see on the Desktop there was no space in the directory name, but in Finder, there was a space in the name.  After closing out of XCode and then renaming the folder to have no spaces the issue was solved and 'pod init' worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me .

first import directory in terminal where your `.xcodeproj` .

then run `pod init` 
it's showing error `([!] No Xcode project found, please specify one)`...then run `pod install` command .. Again it is showing error `([!] No`Podfile' found in the project directory.)`..

then QUIT terminal .. Open again ...

`import directory` in terminal  again Run command `pod init` ..

Now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the projectFolder to 7, Project folder should have the same name as the `.xcodeproj` file has.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

1. called sudo gem install cocoapods and waited for it to install
2. pod setup
3. dragged in my project directory folder "Hello"
4. called pod init

https://www.jianshu.com/p/a3b803457b08

It's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well add my 2 cents. I just installed xcode and react native, following this guide: https://dev.to/rob117/how-to-really-set-up-a-react-native-environment-on-mac-248h

Everything seemed to run as expected at first with `react-native run-ios`...I copied over some react-native files from another project, got some dependency errors, fixed them with npm install, and then I restarted my MacBook. After I booted up again, I ran `react-native run-ios` and got errors about not being able to launch the iPhone 6 simulator. I couldn't find a fix, so I decided to determine if it was my code or if it was xcode or what. So I went to my main projects directory and started a new react-native project, referencing the link I posted above. After everything installed, I did `react-native run-ios` again and boom, everything worked fine.

So then I closed xcode, the simulator and the terminal that runs upon starting react-native. I went back to my first project and ran `react-native run-ios`. boom it's working again, except this strange error `error Could not find the following native modules: RNKeychain, RNVectorIcons. Did you forget to run "pod install" ?`.  I installed cocoapods via brew the first time around, I tried `pod install` but it complains about no xcode file or something. I've tried pod init, but it tells me `No Xcode project found, please specify one`. I ran `pod setup`, no error...seemed to do nothing? I guess it's working because now my simulator is running again.

Maybe I'll just remove the react-native-keychain and react-native-vectoricons npm packages from my package.json and see if it goes away. I don't really understand what coca pods is or why I need it. I'm thinking maybe you should take some time to update xcode, delete node_modules folder and run `npm install` again, spin up a new react-native project and if it works close xocde, simulator and the terminal and then try to go run your project again.

If it was working fine before and you didn't update anything outside of node_modules folder, remove and reinstall often works for me.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I am using ionic, you need to cd to the directory that contains xcode files like (App.xcodeproj + App.xcworkspace) then apply the command

> pod init